# Own SpringSecurity UserDetailsService dont load User - Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security

I wrote my own SpringSecurity UserDetailsService. I used [**this**](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/) tutorial for it. 
The only differents between my configuration and that tutorial is, that I have a xml file for spring framework. But my application didn't work:

The problem is, that `userDao.load(email);` (watch UserDetailsService below) returns null and not an userObject. But if I switch the configuration of SpringSecurity to an inMemoryAuthentication and use `userDao.load(email);` in another context, the service returns the right user.

Stacktrace:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at de.nak.cars.dao.UserDAO.load(UserDAO.java:61)
    at de.nak.cars.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:34)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:102)
    ... 39 more
```

UserDetailsService:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        de.name.cars.model.User user = userDao.load(email); //load returns null, saw in debug mode
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getRoles());
        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);

    }

    private UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(de.name.cars.model.User user,
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> roles) {

        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (UserRole role : roles){
            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()));
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

        return result;
    }

}
```

spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="de.nak.cars" />

    <!-- The data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:h2:Y:/db/nak"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <!-- The session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="de.nak.cars.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">initial-sql.sql</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- The transaction manager -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- The advice -->
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <!-- The pointcut definition -->
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethods" expression="execution(* de.nak.cars.service.*.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceMethods"/>
    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    /** Generated version id. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5464675373969471720L;
    /** The identifier. */
    private Long id;
    /** The user's firstname. */
    private String firstName;
    /** The user's lastname. */
    private String lastName;
    /** The user's student identification number. */
    private String email;
    /** The user's roles. */
    private Set<UserRole> roles;
    /** The user's password. */
    private String password;
    /** Set of user-exam combinations. */
    private Set<ExamKey> examKeys = new HashSet<ExamKey>(0);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", length = 100, nullable = false)
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", length = 100, nullable = false)
    public String getlastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setlastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="USER_USERROLE", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    public Set<UserRole> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<UserRole> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name="PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "examKeyId.user")
    public Set<ExamKey> getExamKeys() {
        return examKeys;
    }

    public void setExamKeys(Set<ExamKey> examKeys) {
        this.examKeys = examKeys;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        User other = (User) obj;
        if (firstName == null) {
            if (other.firstName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
            return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (lastName == null) {
            if (other.lastName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
            return false;
        if (!email.equals(other.email))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName="
                + lastName + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password + ", examKeys=" + examKeys
                + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add your user entity class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to enable transaction management support. In the guide you followed it was done with @EnableTransactionManagement annotation over AppConfig class. In your case you use xml configuration, so you should add `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />` inside your spring-config.xml

Comment: Togehter with the `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` Annotation it works. Thank you.